# Yves Montand : "Télégramme" (pourquoi « mon chéri » au lieu de « ma chérie » ?)

Tags: usage, accord, cinéma, télévision

Paroles :

https://www.paroles.net/yves-montand/paroles-telegramme

Video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILbUdPUO8PE

L'extrait sous question :

> Montand:  Mon chéri...
>
> La téléphoniste:  Comment?
>
> Montand:  Mon chéri...
>
> La téléphoniste:  MON chéri ou Ma chérie? ...
>
> Montand:  Non. Mon chéri...
>
> La téléphoniste:  Bon! Mon chéri... Comme une en-tête de lettre?
>
> Montand:  Oui, si vous voulez... Mon chéri...

Pourquoi Y.M. emploie-t-il **mon chéri** et pas **ma chérie** vu que le récepteur du télégramme est une femme ?

Comment: On pouvait utiliser 'mon petit' pour s'adresser à une jeune femme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peut-être pour faire rire le public ?

Ou peut-être une faute d'inattention parce qu'il avait prévu de commencer par ***mon amour*** puis il a changé d'avis ?

Ou simplement parce que c'était un tic de langage d'Yves Montand ?

Il a plus tard commencé par ***mon chéri*** un vrai télégramme envoyé à Simone Signoret, mais c'est peut-être une conséquence de ce sketch.

> *« Mon chéri, quoi que tu lises, quoi que tu entendes, ne crois rien. Je t'aime, je vous aime. »* Huguette Bouchardeau, *Simone Signoret*, 2005

Comment: mon chéri = être chéri par mon amour, c'est aussi du domaine de l'amour fusionnel